# How could htaccess redirect two hosts to subdirectory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How could both localhost and remote hosts redirect root to a sub-directory?

**Local Host**: domain.localhost
**Remote Host**: domain.com
**Sub Directory**: subdir

```
domain.localhost -> domain.localhost/subdir/<br>
domain.localhost/ -> domain.localhost/subdir/<br>
domain.com-> domain.com/subdir/<br>
www.domain.com -> www.domain.com/subdir/<br>
```

---

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex questions.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.localhost$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain\.localhost/subdir/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/subdir/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I've tried all of the solutions, but unfortunately did't function as expected. Thanks Guys for all of your answers.

Answer (score 1):

For those principles:

```
domain.localhost -> domain.localhost/subdir/
domain.localhost/ -> domain.localhost/subdir/
domain.com-> domain.com/subdir/

www.domain.com -> www.domain.com/subdir/
```

Here are the precise rewriterules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex questions.php
RewriteEngine on

# domain.localhost -> domain.localhost/subdir/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.localhost$
RewriteRule (.*) /subdir/$1 [QSA,L]

# domain.com -> domain.com/subdir/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /subdir/$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

If it doesn't work try without the "`/`":

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex questions.php
RewriteEngine on

# domain.localhost -> domain.localhost/subdir/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.localhost$
RewriteRule (.*) /subdir$1 [QSA,L]

# domain.com -> domain.com/subdir/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /subdir$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

NB: there's no need to make a redirect with `[R]` directive. There's no need to precise the whole domain.

Answer (score 0):

no need to specify the domainname inside your rewrite-rules:

```
RewriteCond $0 !^subdir
RewriteRule (.*) /subdir/$1 [L]
```

(Remember to clear your browsers cache first)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify a full url, Mod Rewrite will make it relative to the domain of the request.  In other words, `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir$1 [R=301,L]` would redirect `http://domain.localhost/blah-blah` to `http://domain.localhost/subdir/blah-blah`

Your config can be condensed into a single RewriteRule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex questions.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir$1 [R=301,L]
```

Since the RewriteRule pattern match will include the initial `/`, i.e. /blah-blah, the rewrite `/subdir$1` will prevent the redirect from causing double slashes.